# Plotting Multiple Date and Value pair columns in Python

Tags: python, pandas, plot, time-series

How can each row in the Python, Pandas Dataframe with multiple pairs of Date and Observation Values be plotted with Dates being on the x-axis and Observation Values on the y-axis?

IndexColumn, Date1,    Value1, Date2,    Value2, Date3,    Value3

xyz,         1/1/2020, 2,      2/2/2020, 3,      3/3/2020, 4

abc,         1/2/2020, 4,      2/6/2020, 7,      3/9/2020, 8

[Dateframe with multiple Date and Value Pairs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvaeq.png)

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two options.

#### Option 1: Reshape the DataFrame

Below, we just grab the Date1,Value1 and Date2,Value2, etc. and then just stack them on top of each other to make a new dataframe.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
rename_func = lambda x: 'Date' if 'Date' in x else 'Value'
new_df = pd.concat([df[['Date'+str(i),'Value'+str(i)]].rename(str,columns=rename_func) for i in [1,2,3]])

# first is a scatter plot, second is a line plot. Uncomment whichever you want!
#plt.scatter(new_df['Date'],new_df['Value'])
#plt.plot(new_df['Date'],new_df['Value'])
```

#### Option 2: Plot as is

Instead of reshaping the data, you could just plot a scatter plot without having to change anything. If you do it this way, you won't be able to easily make a line plot like above.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.scatter(df['Date1'],df['Value1'],color='blue')
plt.scatter(df['Date2'],df['Value2'],color='blue')
plt.scatter(df['Date3'],df['Value3'],color='blue')
```